# How can I clear the drawing canvas in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, drawing

I am new to HTML. Just for the fun. I was making a drawing canvas in HTML by watching a tutorial on YouTube.

The code is simulated here:
https://jsfiddle.net/MasoodSalik/yr1ezp4x/

I am facing 2 problems:

1. When I Clear the canvas, The brush does not work properly as shown in image.
2. When I draw or overshoot the edges of the canvas, brush remains dragging in canvas. I want it to stop drawing as it touches the edges. How can I do it?

   [image: Drawing Canvas Problem brush]

   ```
   *{
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family:sans-serif;

     user-select: none;
     -webkit-user-select:none;
      user-select: none;

   }


   #toolbara{
    width :329px;
    height :40px;
     padding:10px;
     position: relative;
     top:0px;
     background-color:#2f2f2f;
     color: white;
     }


   .radcontrol{
       width : 30px;
      height : 20px;
      background-color:#4f4f4f;
      display:inline-block;
      text-align:center;
   }

   #rad{
     float:left;
   }
   #colour{
    //position: relative;
     float:center;
   }

   .swatch{
     width:20px;
     height:20px;
     border-radius:10px;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     display:inline-block;
     margin-left:5px;
     margin-bottom:50px;
     background-color:cyan;
   }
   .swatch.active{
     border:2px solid white;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) ;

   }
   #save{
       background-color: #4f4f4f;
      // width: 50px;
      padding: 5px;
      position: relative;
     float :right;
     top:-45px;
     right: 60px;
     margin-right:0px;
   }
   #save:hover{
     background-color: #818181;

   }

   #clear{
       background-color: #4f4f4f;
      // width: 50px;
      padding: 5px;
      position: relative;
     float :right;
     top:-45px;
     right: -40px;
    // margin-right:0px;
   }
   #clear:hover{
     background-color: #818181;

   }

   </style>


   <canvas id="canvas" width="325" height="500" style="border:2px solid">
   <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
   </canvas>

   <div id ="toolbara">
       <div id="rad">
           Radius <span id="radval">1</span>
         <div id="decrad" class="radcontrol">-</div>
          <div id="incrad" class="radcontrol">+</div>
        </div>
        <div id="colors">
        </div>
        <div id="save"> Save </div>
        <div id="clear"> Clear </div>
   </div>

   <script>

   var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
   var context=canvas.getContext('2d');
   var radius=5;
   var dragging=false;

   context.beginPath();
   context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   context.fillStyle = "white";
   context.fill();
   context.beginPath();

   context.lineWidth=radius*2;

   var putPoint = function(e){
       if(dragging) {
       context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
       context.stroke();
       context.beginPath();
       context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        context.fill();
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
   }
   }

   var engage=function(e)
   { dragging=true;
      putPoint(e);
   }

   var disengage=function()
   {   
    dragging=false;
   context.beginPath();
   }

       canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',engage);
       canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',disengage);
       canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',putPoint);

    var setRadius = function (newRadius) {
                   if (newRadius < minRad) newRadius = minRad;
                   else if (newRadius > maxRad) newRadius = maxRad;
                   radius = newRadius;
                   context.lineWidth = radius * 2;

                   radSpan.innerHTML = radius;
               }

     ////////////////////////////////////////
    var minRad = 1,
                   maxRad = 10,
                   defaultRad = 1,
                   interval = 1,
                   radSpan = document.getElementById('radval'),
                   decRad = document.getElementById('decrad'),
                   incRad = document.getElementById('incrad');

               decRad.addEventListener('click', function () {
                   setRadius(radius - interval);
               });
               incRad.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    setRadius(radius < interval ? interval : radius + interval);
               });

               setRadius(defaultRad);
     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   var colors = ['black', 'white', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']; //Color array to select from
   /*Handles the creation of color*/
   for(var i=0, n=colors.length;i<n; i++){
   var swatch = document.createElement('nav');
   swatch.className = 'swatch';
   swatch.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
   swatch.addEventListener('click',setSwatch);
   document.getElementById('colors').appendChild(swatch);
   }
   /*set color*/
   function setColor(color){
   context.fillStyle = color;
   context.strokeStyle = color;
   var active = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
   if(active){
   active.className = 'swatch';
   }
   }
   function setSwatch(e){
   //identify swatch
   var swatch = e.target;
   //set color
   setColor(swatch.style.backgroundColor);
   //give active class
   swatch.className += ' active';
   }
   setSwatch({target: document.getElementsByClassName('swatch')[0]}); //set default swatch

   //////////////////////////////////////

    var button = document.getElementById('save');
               button.addEventListener('click', saveImage)

    function saveImage()          
    {     //   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                 var data = canvas.toDataURL();

                window.open(data,'_blank,','location=0,menubar=0')
                //  button.href = dataURL;
               };

    var butonclear = document.getElementById('clear');
               butonclear.addEventListener('click', clearImage)

    function clearImage()          
    {      
               context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
   context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   context.fillStyle = "white";
   context.fill();
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);


         };          

   </script>


   <!link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B7ZbA61nROnAMkFzSDVoOWdCWkk/noselect.css"></!link></!link>`
   ```

Comment: I don't have time to write and research a formal answer, but I think your problem is that you are setting the fillStyle to white and then just leaving it. You should temporarily set it to white for the clear and then set it back to what it was before. It might be some other property instead, but the stuttering problem goes away when you choose a color again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Brush doesn't work properly cause when you call clearImage() you are changing `context.fillStyle` to white, also `context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);` it's unnecessary. 
   Look at that reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/yr1ezp4x/2/
2. There you will have a bit more work. Inside functions triggered by mouse events you have to check if mouse is over your canvas.